# Struts 2 URL won't substitute with correct value

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

I am following the [Struts 2 Tutorial - Using Struts 2 Tags](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/using-struts-2-tags.html)

So far everything have been working as expected until I added the following to index.jsp:

```
<s:url action="hello" var="helloLink">
    <s:param name="userName">Bruce Phillips</s:param>
</s:url>
<p><a href="${helloLink}">Hello Bruce Phillips</a></p>
```

Expected result is that the anchor-link (Hello Bruce Phillips) should be substituted with corresponding URL for hello.action with parameter userName encoded, however no substitution occurs and this is how the element renders:

```
<p>
    <a href="${helloLink}">Hello Bruce Phillips</a>
</p>
```

Is there anything wrong with my syntax?

Environment:

- Tried in both GlassFish 2.1 and 3.1.1, same unexpected result.
- Struts 2.2.3.1
- Mac (Lion) with java6 jdk
- Tag definition: <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If *no* JSP EL evaluates, check these:

- The web.xml is not declared as Servlet 2.4 or higher.
- The @page is configured with isELIgnored=true.
- The web.xml is configured with `<el-ignored>true</el-ignored>` in `<jsp-config>`.

I'm guessing the first one.

@user873670's answer will also work, but is not necessary in a properly-configured app.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that version 2.3 was declared in the web.xml. I changed to 2.5 and the example now works as expected.

Comment: It was tricky for me to change from versioon 2.3, so please find here what worked for me. Change the beginning of web.xml with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">`

Answer (score 2):

Struts 2 doesn't do JSP evaluations, it does OGNL evaluations. Simply put it's %{variable} and #variable instead of ${variable}.

When we talk Struts2 tags it would mean that you should replace

```
    <a href="${helloLink}">
```

with

```
    <a href='<s:property value="helloLink"/>'>
```

or

```
    <s:a href="%{helloLink}" >Edit</s:a>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: It works for me. I am using Servlet version 3.1. Thanks.